# stream video from pi camera to browser of remote server

Tags: video, camera, streaming, raspbian, remote-server

I have configured camera on raspberry pi and been able to watch live video streaming from pi camera to browser of any machine that is connected to same network. I have used mjpg-streamer to do so. Now I am looking for some open source solution that can enable me to stream video from pi camera to browser of some remote server. Can anybody guide me how can i stream video from pi camera to some remote system ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Raspberry Pi you will need to download netcat. On your computer you will need to download mplayer or mplayer2.
Once you have downloaded those, enter this into the terminal of the Raspberry Pi.

`raspivid -t 0 -w 640 -h 480 -ih -fps 20 -o - | nc -l 2222`

Then on the computer you want to view the stream with, type

`mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es ffmpeg://tcp://IP_OF_PI:2222`

I've found the delay using netcat and mplayer2 is the least.